# Get "jstat" Utility for IBM J9 (Java 1.6)

Tags: java, java-6

I am maintaining several Linux systems (SUSE SLES 11 SP3) that are running Java 1.6 (IBM J9) and a Java application which I wish to be able to monitor more closely. I'd like to be able to gather statistics on heap usage, however the "jstat" tool does not seem to be supplied by IBM in their JDK (unless I'm just confused, which could very much be so, as I'm just starting to familiarize my self with java). It looks like it's generally bundled with the Oracle Java JDK..

What I'm wondering is if there is any way to get this utility installed to be compatible with a Java application running in a IBM J9 VM, or am I pretty much SOL? And if it's not available, is there another way to gather the size of the heap and how close the application is to running out of memory?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're looking for IBM Health Center: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/jdk/tools/healthcenter/

> Health Center is a quick to deploy, small impact live monitoring tool running on either IBM Java Virtual machines or IBM SDK for Node.js. By gathering information on a wide range of areas such as method profiling, Garbage collection and memory usage, Health Center provides recommendations and analysis to help you improve the performance and efficiency of your application. Health Center can save the data obtained from monitoring an application and load it again for analysis at a later date.